# How do I make a discrete voltage detector?

Tags: comparator, voltage-reference, voltage-detector

I would like to design a circuit which has outputs LOW when the voltage it is connected to is below a threshold, like 3.3V.

There are some ic's you can buy to do this, but I would like to make my own so I can tweak the detection voltage for each specific application. From looking at the datasheets for these chips, it looks like they create a reference voltage and then use a comparator to compare the input to the reference, then that drives a transistor. Does that seem correct? Sorry if this is very simple, I am a noob :)

Thanks

Example IC by microchip: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001434K.pdf

Another example by ST: https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/135f/0900766b8135f981.pdf

-Edit:

I don't need a very accurate device, the threshold voltage can vary quite a lot for my application. I found a voltage reference which is quite cheap and might be suitable, but I guess the reference voltage needs to be lower than the input voltage will ever be.

https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Voltage-References_TL431_C181103.html

Comment: What do you need in terms of accuracy, precision, repeatability between circuits, etc? Since you are looking for a discrete design, you either require reference ICs or else you go to some significant design (even then, likely unable to beat an IC without custom tweaks and calibration and re-calibration from time to time.) If you can accept some variation one circuit to another as well as over operating temperature ranges, then discrete and cheap and tweakable thresholds with hysteresis are all possible.

Comment: @jonk I dont need very high accuracy, precision, or repeatability. For the 3.3V example, a max threshold voltage anywhere from 3.45V to 3.15V would be fine. I will definitely use a reference IC. I found a very cheap one here: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Voltage-References_TL431_C181103.html

Comment: Yeah. I have buckets of TL431's. The variability of BJTs from the same family might be \$\pm 20\:\text{mV}\$ for their \$V_\text{BE}\$ (at the same temp.) Without compensation (not hard to add some) account for another \$-1.8\text{ to }-2.4\:\frac{\text{mV}}{^\circ\text{C}}\$ for operating temperature differences. But a crafty design can do a lot to minimize temperature variation. (It will look like a parabolic curve, which you can work to "flatten out" pretty well with a good design.) Your range is probably achievable with the TL431 without too much added work. Without it? Trickier.

Comment: Oh. Two TL431's and you are more than golden. If you are willing to spend two on a simple circuit. See [this TI paper for some ideas](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva987/slva987.pdf).

Comment: Or you can look here, as well: [schmitt trigger](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378124/bjt-schmitt-trigger-threshold-voltage-calculation).

Comment: yeah, have a look at some of the example circuits on the TL431 data sheet. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf

Comment: @Jasen and Jonk Thanks you guys a lot for the links and advice! I think  I will start off simple and not worry about temperature compensation too much, and see how it works, then get more fancy if needed. I will need to do some more reading to make sure I understand the circuit well, then i'll dig in.

Comment: Just to be sure, you *do not* intend this device to be powered by the very same voltage it is measuring, right? Is it to be powered by its own batteries, or mains?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQUMO7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some of the resistors should not be 100 ohms.

Comment: it's much easier to use a TL431 and a few  resistors.

Comment: How well do circuits like this work without matched BJTs like the 2N3906?